# Salesforce DX Proxy issues

Tags: salesforcedx

I successfully installed Salesforce DX on Windows but I cannot use it because of proxy issues.

I already configured the environment variables as described at: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm but I encounter the following errors:

```
sfdx update
! Get https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/sfdxstable/manifest.json: Proxy Authentication Required

sfdx force
Installing required plugins for force...
!    Error installing package.
!    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
!    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sfdx\\lib\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sfdx\\lib\\npm\\cli.js" "install" "salesforcedx"
!    npm ERR! node v6.9.5
!    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
!    npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
!
!    npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up
!    npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
!    npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
!    npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
!    npm ERR! network
!    npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
!    npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
!
!    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
!    npm ERR!     D:\Utilisateurs\XXXX\AppData\Local\sfdx\plugins\npm-debug.log
!
!    Try running again with SFDX_DEBUG=1 to see more output.
```

I tried both with and without the authentication part for the following environment variables:

```
npm config set https-proxy
npm config set http-proxy
npm config set proxy
set HTTP_PROXY
set HTTPS_PROXY
```

Any suggestions? Are there specific IPs or domains to open at the proxy level ? Should we wait for the offical release?

Comment: did you manage how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

hey did you try setting proxies for npm 
like this:

```
npm config set https-proxy https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set proxy https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set sslVerify false
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

then creating a Environment variable

```
HTTP_PROXY >> https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
```

note: not mandatory to set proxy as https as above it can be http as well
same goes with username 
your proxy can be like  http://proxy.company.com:8080 for all above variables

Answer (score 1):

@djmat - From the error it looks like you have not provided your proxy credentials. Did you try providing that? Use the format below: Replace the username/password/port with appropriate values.

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set proxy http://yourusername@username.com:yourpassword1@proxy.proxy.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://yourusername@username.com:yourpassword1@proxy.proxy.com:8080
```