# Authentication into Dev Hub does not work in CLI

Tags: salesforcedx, error, login, salesforcedx-cli, dev-hub

I type in Salesforce CLI the following command:

> $ sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a DevHub

My browser opens up a login form. I pick the org which has Dev Hub enabled. Then in browser I am getting redirected to the page which tells me:

> This page isn’t working
>
> localhost didn’t send any data.
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

And at the same time in CLI I see the following:

> ERROR:  tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80.

[image]
[image]

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your local machine running a firewall or other security software that might impact connections?

Comment: @DavidReed, I thought about it as well, but I do not know how to check whether or not there is a security software present. I am using my personal laptop and my home network, which I would expect to not have any proxy or secure software.

Comment: Hi, 
If you are using proxy. You need to do this. 
Check this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/194719/salesforce-dx-proxy-issues. It might be help to you.